# What should i do to avoid single point of failure in cassandra?

Tags: nosql, cassandra

I am using phpcassa library to get and set data into cassandra which i have installed on 2 servers.... I am making connection with my seed node using CassandraConn::add_node('***.***.**.***', 9160); so while insertion automatically gets replicate on other node in cluster... but if my seed node dies (if i shut down the cassandra process) then my insertion will not work and i am unable to get data from the other node too:(, so am i doing the right thing... because in this way their is no use of cluster then.. as ideally if my one node dies in the other node should respond me.. any help will be appreciated?

Answer (score 3):

Connect with RRDNS instead of a single host. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS

(You can also use a load balancer but that is usually overkill here.)

Comment: In the case of RRDNS, you will want multiple DNS servers with the same static configuration (or possibly a more complex, dynamic setup). In the case of a load balancer, you will want two load balancers heartbeated to each other and with a floating IP address between them.

Answer (score 1):

Most Cassandra clients will let you directly specify multiple server addresses, and will try them in turn if one fails.

I haven't used phpcassa (only pycassa) but the API docs at http://thobbs.github.com/phpcassa/api/index.html seem to suggeest that you can specify multiple servers.

Round-robin is another alternative as per the previous answer.